# NotificationListenerService - get whatsapp messages text for -4.4

Tags: android, service, notifications

i'm building an application that working on the same idea like this one -

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stallware.dashdow.whatsapp.lite

- when whatsapp notification arrive, do something with the notification text - for example, in this application when notification arrive, the NLSerivce create a bubble with the contact name and content,

my question is how can i get this data? 
there is null in the "sbn.getNotification().tickerText", i found solution for 4.4+, :

```
TITLE = (String) sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
TEXT = (String) sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

gives me all the information i need, but the 'extras' requires api 19 + (kitkat..), but i need this information to older versions like 4.3..

what am i missing? what is the other way to parse the data?

- another question (same idea..) is how can i use accessability service for android 4.0 - 4.3? i need to know when the notification is removed from the notification bar and i couldnt understand how can i know it when using AS..

from the Dashdow What App information -

"For devices with Android 4.3 or higher we use the notification access service which you have to activate. 
Devices with 4.0 or higher will have to enable the accessability service in system."

any idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CharSequence[] lines = 
extras.getCharSequenceArray(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES);
if(lines != null && lines.length > 0) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (CharSequence msg : lines)
      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
         sb.append(msg.toString());
         sb.append('\n');
      }
   return sb.toString().trim();
}
CharSequence chars = 
extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT);
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(chars))
   return chars.toString();
```